# Higher contact voltage but lower current for 5.5×2.1 mm DC female port

Tags: voltage, current, connector

I'm currently trying to power a 58.8 V device with a 58.8 V and 3 A power supply. However, I'd need the contact to be a 5.5×2.1 mm female DC port and the highest I could find was rated at a contact voltage of 50 V and a maximum current of 10 A. Would it be safe and okay to use the higher voltage power supply with this 50 V rated DC port since the current is much lower? The current female DC port comes with 20AWG copper wire.

Should I instead opt for a generic 5.5×2.1 mm DC port but solder 18AWG wire to withstand the higher voltage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last paragraph indicates some confusion about max. current/voltage ratings and their relevance in the design:

The maximum voltage is determined by the quality of the insulation of the port. If you apply a higher voltage, chances are, that the insulation will be damaged, or - in the worst case - completely fail, which can be dangerous.

The maximum current is determined by the contacts/wire thickness. A higher current means the temperature rises in the contacts/cables to the point of destruction, so if you need a higher current capability, you need a thicker cable.

For your case: No, your port would not be okay. If you are lucky, 50 V are the "recommended" operating area - if your datasheet has a section "absolute maximum ratings" the part might handle higher voltages as well, although that is generally not recommended.

Your solution of soldering a thicker cable to the port also does not work, as I explained above, this does not increase the voltage rating.